# ImageView doesn't show image from intent in java android

Tags: java, android, imageview, uri

I've tried a couple different ways to show a chosen image from the gallery in a imageView. In the MainActivity I let the user choose an Image from Gallery and use an intent in the MainActivity, to send the uri of the image to the NextActivity and set the uri to the imageView, but it's not working. I can't see the Image. In the debug mode I see the uri in the variable which I set to the ImageView but it doesn't show the image.

My code

MainActivity.java onCreate method

```
<!-- language: java -->

if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && requestCode == PICK_IMAGE){
            imageUri = data.getData();
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, NextActivity.class );
            if(imageUri != null){
                intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
                startActivity(intent);
            }

        }
```

NextActivity.java onCreate method

```
<!-- language: java -->

ImageView imgView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
Intent intent = getIntent();
String image_path = intent.getStringExtra("imageUri");
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(image_path);
imgView.setImageURI(fileUri);
```

I've tried to send the Uri as it is with intent, converted as a String and reconverted and so on. I don't know.

NextActivity XML

```
<!-- language: xml -->

<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="396dp"
        android:layout_height="450dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.466"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(image_path);
imgView.setImageURI(null); 
imgView.setImageURI(fileUri);
```

Comment: doesn't work, same happens, means no image is shown

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, this would be just one activity (perhaps using two fragments), rather than two activities.

But, if you want to stick with this structure, you will need to change this:

```
        imageUri = data.getData();
        Intent intent = new Intent (this, NextActivity.class );
        if(imageUri != null){
            intent.putExtra("imageUri", imageUri.toString());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

to:

```
        imageUri = data.getData();

        if (imageUri != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent (this, NextActivity.class);
            intent.setData(imageUri);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
```

and change:

```
String image_path = intent.getStringExtra("imageUri");
Uri fileUri = Uri.parse(image_path);
```

to:

```
Uri fileUri = intent.getData();
```

Without that, [`NextActivity` will not have rights to use the content identified by the `Uri`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/08/10/uri-access-lifetime-shorter-than-you-might-think.html).

Also, please replace `setImageURI()` with an image-loading library, such as Glide or Picasso.

Comment: still not working, App crashes after choosing an image in the gallery.

Comment: @Nathan: Then you might want to consider asking a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide the updated [mcve], including the complete stack trace.